# How to process string in php

Tags: php, string

I have string like this

```
$str="absdbsasd k=12312 sdasd l=89879 m=ken asddq casdasd"
```

and the output should be like this

the question is how to process the string on variable $str to get output which is like this

```
k=12312
l=89879
m=ken asddq casdasd
```

I have tried to implement parse_str after I replace the space character (' ') into '&', but the output still got the wrong answer

```
k=12312
l=89879
m=ken
```

Could anybody help me..

Comment: There seems to be little targetable logic in that string to achieve the output you want. The value of `m` has spaces in it, which will complicate things.

Comment: Why isn't k parsed as `k=12312 sdasd`? Why have support for spaces for `m` but not for `k`?

Comment: this is the original sintaks that i've tried..
$str="absdbsasd k=12312 sdasd l=89879 m=ken asddq casdasd"
$str = str_replace(" ","&",$str);
parse_str($str);
echo $k."<br>";
echo $l."<br>";
echo $m;

Because i want the output something like that. k means a number and m means a string..

Could you help me..

Comment: Will variables (keys) always be single characters? And also, according to how your output for `m` should be, then for `k` it should be `k=12312 sdasd`. Shouldn't it be so? In that case, it won't quite be possible to generalise a code, unless there is a clear distinction as to why the space isn't parsed for `k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the logic is that identifiers are word chars ending with a `=` and values ends when the next identifier comes, but if the value starts with numbers then only the first word of numbers needed for the value, i would go about it like this:

```
$str="absdbsasd k=12312 sdasd l=89879 m=ken asddq casdasd";

$parts = preg_split('/(\w+=)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$result = array();
$prev_was_an_identifier = false;
$last_identifier = null;
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if ($prev_was_an_identifier) {
        if (preg_match('/^\d+/', $part)) {
            $result[$last_identifier] = preg_replace('/^(\d+).*/', '$1', $part);
        } else {
            $result[$last_identifier] = $part;
        }   
        $prev_was_an_identifier = false;
    } elseif (preg_match('/=$/', $part)) {
        $prev_was_an_identifier = true;
        $last_identifier = mb_substr($part, 0, -1);
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
array (
  'k' => '12312',
  'l' => '89879',
  'm' => 'ken asddq casdasd',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to define the structure of the string something like this:

```
$str = "$first_value k=$secound_value l=$third_value m=$forth_value";
```

If the structure is as I have written, then It's pretty impossible to get what you need, since there are no sepperators or any other types of way to determine where one value ends and another value begins.
Look at this example:

```
$str="absdbsasd k=12312 sdasd l=s l=8987 l=s 9 m=ken asddq casdasd"
```

There is no way to teel where the real `l=` starts.

If you would add some seperators like `'` ( and make sure they don't appear in the values, the you can get something like this:

```
$str="'absdbsasd' k='12312 sdasd l=s' l='8987 l=s 9' m='ken asddq casdasd'"
```

And then you can do a `preg_match` or `preg_split` check and get your desired values.

Or, suggested, just make an array in the 1st place.